# C++ работа с файлами и папками

Tags: c++, файловая-система

Изучаю озвученную тему - хочу разобраться, как просматривать/переименовывать/удалять папки. На данный момент нарыл:

1. fstream - насколько понял, там только функционал для
   чтения/изменения файлов, поправьте, если не прав;
2. direct.h - функции есть, но подозреваю, что это наследие С - уместно
   ли его использовать для С-плюсов? немного напрягает, что, внимание цитата: "
   Удалить и переименовать можно только пустую директорию";
3. есть еще некая библиотека boost, пока не вникал что она такое...

Посоветуйте, опытные люди, куда дальше копать?

Comment: Пока нет С++20, используйте direct.h и не заморачивайтесь, можно ли использовать "наследие С". Или, если хотите - используйте вообще API конкретной операционной системы, но это еще дальше от стандартного и переносимого С++ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтение/запись файлов поддерживается очень давно в STL http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream. Это не должно вызвать особых трудностей, а вот переименование файлов, создание каталогов и переименование каталогов, можно сделать одним из следующий способов:

1. Поддержка файловой системы (переименование файлов, создание каталогов) в STL должна быть в C++17 стандарте(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs).
2. Также вы можете использовать boost Filesystem Library(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm). По сути fs C++17 основан на нём.
3. Либо использовать API операционной системы. Например для Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363950(v=vs.85).aspx.
4. Можно использовать сторонюю бибиотеку, например Qt также имеет функции для работы с каталоками и файлми, например QDir: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html

Answer (score 2):

c++ до 11 стандарта точно не имел встроенных функций для работы с каталогами/папками. Есть только апи целевых платформ. То, что они "си подобны" - ничего страшного.

Сейчас появился [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). Его добавили в 17 стандарте, но нужно смотреть, какие компиляторы его поддерживают. (по факту - gcc только в транке - то есть, самый свежий 7.3 ещё не поддерживает, clang - даже в транке не поддерживает, 2017 студия поддерживает. Качество поддержки ещё нужно тестить).

Можно также использовать буст, в нем есть готовые обертки - https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

А можно не переживать, и написать свое или использовать фреймворки, тот же Qt.

Comment: 2017 студия НЕ поддерживает. Поддержка только эксперементальная и кривая, так же и в clang. Удивительно, но на данный момент нет ни одного компилятора (библиотеки от них), которая бы поддерживала filesystem в полной мере.

Comment: поддерживает. только что проверил. как минимум версия 15.6.5. Только нужно использовать `std::experimental::filesystem`.

Comment: Ну так а я о чём говорю? «Поддержка только экспериментальная и кривая». Т.е. можно сказать, что поддержки нет совсем, т.к. полноценно работать с тем, что есть — невозможно.

Comment: я же и написал, что поддержку нужно тестить.